# Eloquent relations retrieving all rows from table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have 2 Models: `Post` and `Image`. Each `Image` is associated with a `Post` and one `Post` can have many `Image`s, as its shown below.

```
public function post()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Post::class, 'id', 'post_id');
}

public function images()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Image::class, 'post_id', 'id');
}
```

But, When I try to retrieve Post with a `id:1` it using:

```
$post = Post::find($id);
$post->images;
```

It brings me ALL posts, not the specific one, as you can see below:

[image: Return when try to access the relation from a specific instance]

However, when I return using this syntax:

```
$post->with(['images'])->where('id', $post->id)->get();
```

[image: Return using 'where' method]

it works fine, but the first method should work as well, shouldn't it?

Comment: that should not happen, did you `dd($post)` right after the line `$post->images;`?

Comment: I'm a little lost, `$post->images` is returning the linked collection? The collection you linked to is a list of posts, `$post->images` should not be returning any posts at all, only the images associated with that post.

Comment: That's the result of de dd($post) after $post->images http://i.imgur.com/X2OcZAD.png

Comment: Sir Alec, the result of dd($post->images); http://i.imgur.com/Znatrrg.png

Comment: the result of dd($post->with(['images'])->get()); http://i.imgur.com/Yw4BNHH.png

Comment: plz post the result of `dd($post->images()->toSql())`

Comment: @Newtz what are you returning? I think this is the root of the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to get one post by post_id and all images belong to it you can try it:

```php
$post = Post::with(['images'])->findOrFail($id);
```